# Vscode debugger quits as soon as it starts?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I didn't change any configuration settings, but python debugger in vscode malfunctions.

When I use `breakpoint()` explicitly, it works,
but when I use `F5` to start debugging, it automatically ends without any execution.

I googled all the spaces, but I cannot find the reason why debugger does not work.
(It originally worked.)

I sincerely need your help.